# QGIS 3.16.4 crashes after opening 3D map view

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, 3d

I have a problem with QGIS 3.16.4 3D Map Viewer.
When I try to open the viewer, QGIS crashes immediately. This happens both when I use only OSM as basemap, without data layer, but also when I visualize a simple point layer with 6 points. Does anyone have similar problems or a fix for this?

QGIS Info
QGIS Version: 3.16.4-Hannover
QGIS code revision: 654e76b
Compiled against Qt: 5.11.2
Running against Qt: 5.11.2
Compiled against GDAL: 3.1.4
Running against GDAL: 3.1.4

System Info
CPU Type: x86_64
Kernel Type: winnt
Kernel Version: 10.0.19041

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug. You can report the issue to [QGIS Github page](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues).

**Edit:** Already reported as a bug -> [Issue #42402](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/42402)